# In multi dropdown , How can i get the currently removed value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I get the currently removed value from a multi dropdown box.

For example

```
<select name="select[]" multiple id="select1">
    <option value="1"> 1 </option>
    <option value="2"> 2 </option>
     <option value="3"> 3 </option>
</select>"
```

I first select 1 then 2 and after that I deselect 2 . I need a j query to get me the value 2. Is that possible.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I think this is what event listeners are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<script>
var last_value = 1;//put the value default of your select
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#select1').change(function(){
       alert(last_value);
       last_value = $(this).val();
   });
});

</script>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vvXRS/)

Comment: Glad t help you, if the answer solved your question accept it to help other guys with your same problem @user2045980